# How to pin an image in the center of sprite rect

Tags: python, pygame

Sprite class. I wanted to make the hitbox of a square character smaller than the sprite itself, but I ran into a problem that I don't know how to pin the image in the middle. Is it possible to pin a picture for the Sprite class not at the rect's coordinates 0,0, but for example -20, -20 (so that the picture is in the middle)? Or is the only option is to create a second Rect for the hitbox? It's just inconvenient because you can't find an intersection with a group of sprites through a simple method because it only works with self.rect
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that can be handled automatically with [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite). Either you have to add a second rectangle (`htibox`) for collision detection and implement collision detection manually or you have to implement drawing the sprite and do it manually.

Howevver, if you have a large image with a small object or character sprite on it, you can find the bounds of the object [`pygame.Surface.get_bounding_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_bounding_rect) (of course this works only if the area around the object or character is transparent):

```py
hitbox = image.get_bounding_rect()
```

[image]

Also see [How to get the correct dimensions for a pygame rectangle created from an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65361582/how-to-get-the-correct-dimensions-for-a-pygame-rectangle-created-from-an-image/65361896#65361896).

One option could be to get a [`subsurface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface) of the original sprite with the actual boundaries of the character. This shrinks the image to the actual size of the character on the image. e.g.:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, cx, cy, image):
        super().__init__() 
        self.rect = image.get_bounding_rect()
        self.image = image.subsurface(self.rect)
        self.rect.center = (cx, cy)
```

---

To pin an image in the center of a hit box, get the center of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) and the bounding rectangle of the image.
Set the center of the bounding rectangle with the center of the image and use the bounding rectangle of the image to [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) the image:

```py
center = hitbox.center
image_rect = image.get_rect()
image_rect.center = center
screen.blit(image, image_rect)
```

This all can be written with one line of code:

```py
screen.blit(image, image.get_rect(center = hitbox.center))
```

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
image = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
image.fill("orange")
hitbox = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 50, 50)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    run = not any(e for e in pygame.event.get() if e.type == pygame.QUIT)
    hitbox.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    screen.fill("white")
    screen.blit(image, image.get_rect(center = hitbox.center))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, "yellow", hitbox)
    pygame.display.update()
```